# 2457164.78236111 date in Sqlite.

Tags: sqlite

how to convert 2457164.78236111 date to readable date? Or how would i compare this date with an input date? I am reading this date which is stored as float on sqlite database using biometric diverse.  Am trying to come up with calculated reports as it is used to control students movement during 4 meals. Breakfast,  tea, lunch and dinner.  Please assist.  I couldn't write my sample code as am using my phone right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you look at [this documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and particularly try to use the `julianday()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`2457164.78236111` looks like a Julian date. You can use the [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to convert it. For example:

```
sqlite> select datetime(2457164.78236111);
2015-05-22 06:46:36
```

Comment: I get 1970-01-01 rather that the actual date when I use datetime(colum name) what might i be getting wrong.  Coding from netbeans in java

Comment: The date comes out as zero for some reason, and the unixepoch 0 is that date. Edit your question to desvribe the issue in detail.

Comment: On my sqlite database the time students access the turnstile is recorded as 2457164.78236111. So i want to utilise this record to calculate how many students came for breakfast or tea or lunch using time and dates.